# filtering works on shareoint list view but not through external app list view

Tags: sharepoint

i have used filter to view a list e.g show items only when the following is true

user assigned is equal to [me]

Now when i login in sharepoint with this user the user only sees the items assigned to him.

However by accessing the list from webservice in an external app the user after logging with his credentials can see all items of the list.

What can i do so that the from external app ( adobe air app ) only the filter view of the list is seen .

( i am using moss 2007 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set proper permissions on the list items.

A view is just that, a view of the data, and does not affect the list item data in any way.

Sharepoint has quite a few entrypoints to access data. The proper way to restrict access is to have the right list/item permissions.

One way you could do this is to restrict permissions to the whole list and have an Event Receiver attached to the list and on item update etc, check the assigned user (which I presume is just a column of the list) and set the appropriate permissions for that user.

Comment: the problem is that .. if i give the user the permission to access the list using event receiver on item update . the user will be able to see access the whole list ( all items ) , whereas i want the user to have access to only the items he is assigned to

Comment: I believe sharepoint can assign permissions to specific list items. I didn't meant the whole list, obviously.

Comment: ok . is there an example on the internet to help me implement it ?

Comment: Perhaps this will help: http://www.sharepoint-tips.com/2007/03/sample-event-handler-to-set-permissions.html